# React change array of input value in material ui TextField dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, input, material-ui

I'm trying to change `input` `value` of my project name in an array of available projects:-

```js
// lets say i've projects like so
const projects = [
  { _id: 1, name: 'Project 1' },
  { _id: 2, name: 'Project 2' },
  { _id: 3, name: 'Project 3' }
]

const Projects = () = {
  // declaration of state
  const [projectName, setProjectName] = useState('')
  const [projectId, setProjectId] = useState('')
  const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false) 

  // handle submission of updated input
  useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      if(isSubmit) {
        // do fetch post submission to server

        // reset everything back
        setProjectName('')
        setIsSubmit(false)
      }
    })();
  }, [isSubmit])

  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Submission</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            {projects && projects.map(project => (
              <form 
                key={project._id}
                onSubmit={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault()
                  setProjectId(project._id)
                  setIsSubmit(true)
                }}
              >
                <td>
                  <TextField
                    required
                    label="Name" 
                    value={project.name} 
                    onChange={(e) => setProjectName(e.target.value)}    
                  />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Button type="submit">Update</Button>
                </td>
              </form>
             ))}
           </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
     </>
  )
}
```

Unfortunately, since the `value={project.name}`, the `onChange` event will basically wouldn't work at all in this case.
Btw, this also will introduce new problem where all `input` TextField of the following array will also be updated.

How can I achieve this with React? Doing this with Vanilla JavaScript was much simpler. Don't know how can I achieve this with React tho. Or this way of doing it, is not recommended? Instead, I should create a `Modal` or something that can handle the changes of project name individually?

My goal is to enable direct update from the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

So, About the first problem:

> since the value={project.name}, the onChange event will basically wouldn't work at all

That's because your `onChange` uses `setProjectName`, that's binded (because of useState) to `projectName` variable.

If you use `value={projectName}` the `onChange` will work, but won't do what you want.

To achieve this is to let the React state manage all the project array:

```
// Your initial data.
const projectsDefault = [
  { _id: 1, name: 'Project 1' },
  { _id: 2, name: 'Project 2' },
  { _id: 3, name: 'Project 3' }
]

const Projects = () => {
  // The only needed state to manage projects
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState(projectsDefault)
  
  const [projectId, setProjectId] = useState('')
  const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false)
  
  // You can write it on the "onChange" event, but it's better to have a handle function.
  // Also, i'm using the index, but you can use the ID, it's just a example.
  const handleNameChange = (name, index) => {
      // You can use a functional setState, so you get the old value and do some updates on it, and return the new state.
      setProjects(oldState => {
          oldState[index].name = name
          return oldState
      })
  }

  // handle submission of updated input
  useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      if(isSubmit) {
        // do fetch post submission to server

        setIsSubmit(false)
      }
    })();
  }, [isSubmit])

  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Submission</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            {projects && projects.map((project, index) => (
              <form 
                key={project._id}
                onSubmit={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault()
                  setProjectId(project._id)
                  setIsSubmit(true)
                }}
              >
                <td>
                  <TextField
                    required
                    label="Name" 
                    value={project.name} 
                    onChange={(e) => handleNameChange(e.target.value, index)}    
                  />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Button type="submit">Update</Button>
                </td>
              </form>
             ))}
           </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
     </>
  )
}
```

Comment: it's not working? I neither can't delete nor update the input value

Comment: I can only add or delete just one letter

Comment: This does not trigger change of value property.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is near to finished. As of my react 17.0.2 it does not detect the array has changed so this needs to be faked.

```
const [changed, setChanged] = useState(0)
const randomize = ()=> setChanged(Math.random())

 const handleNameChange = (name, index) => {
  // You can use a functional setState, so you get the old value and do some updates on it, and return the new state.
  setProjects(oldState => {
      oldState[index].name = name
      return oldState
  })
  randomize();
  }
```

React needs to think that something changed, editin